# Can I write queries for different date format (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Tables

- `BOOK` (ISBN, Author_ID,Author_Name, Title, No_Of_Copies)
- `STUDENT` (Student_ID, Name, Address, Course)
- `LOAN` (Student_ID, ISBN, Due_Date)

Write a SQL statement to list the student IDs of students who have all of their borrowed books overdue (in your SQL query, you can use Due-Date> "2-0CT-2008" to test if a book is overdue)

```
SELECT Student_Id
FROM   LOAN
WHERE  Due_Date > '2-OCT-2008'
```

Is the above query correct, can I write the data format in the above format instead of

```
SELECT Student_Id
FROM   LOAN
WHERE  Due_Date > '2-10-2008'
```

Comment: I recommend that you use the ISO format: `WHERE Due_Date > '2008-10-02'`. It's a good habit to pick up early when you learn SQL Server

Comment: Can I use the OCT in the date format,if so How can I change it in my MSSQL server!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server's locale `2-10-2008` can mean February 10 or October 2:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '2-10-2008')

SET DATEFORMAT MDY
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '2-10-2008')
```

Things are apparently more stable if you spell out the month name. `2-OCT-2008` always mean October 2, 2008.

However, I recommend that you use the ISO date format:

```
SELECT Student_Id
FROM   LOAN
WHERE  Due_Date > '2008-10-02'
```